# Generate public static final int for intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, hotkeys

Is there a quick way generate a bunch of constants for Intellij.  Like maybe I type

```
VARIABLE_A = 10;
VARIABLE_B = 20;
...
```

And the use some shortcut in add `public static final int` in front of all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html):

[image: psfi]

Type `psfi` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to expand it.

With the help of the [multiple cursors](http://vojtechruzicka.com/intellij-idea-tips-tricks-multiple-cursors/) you can do it for several lines at a time.